# How can I get the position of Powerpoint Mac in my screen?

Tags: vba, macos, applescript, powerpoint

Using AppleScript with Apple event I can get the position of powerpoint Mac, But it needs assistive access.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Microsoft PowerPoint" 
        properties of UI element 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

How can I access the position without assistive access, Is it possible with VBA or shell script?

Comment: Confused: you mention retrieving the position of *Powerpoint* (an application), but your code block is for obtaining properties of a GUI object.  Can you clarify what you're trying to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code block is trying to retrieve the properties of a GUI object in the front window.  However, *position* is not one of the properties that is attributed to the `UI element` class.

If you're trying to get the position of *Powerpoint*'s window, you're in luck: you don't need assistive access.  Both *System Events* and *Powerpoint* can relay positional information of windows as standard properties.

Using *Powerpoint*:

```
tell application "Microsoft Powerpoint" to return the bounds of the active window
    --> e.g. {260, 23, 1280, 800}
```

This returns a list of four integers, the first two of which represent the coordinates of the window's upper-left corner, and the last two of which represent the coordinates of the bottom-right corner.

Using *System Events*:

```
tell application "System Events" to get [position, size] of window 1 of process "Microsoft Powerpoint"
    --> e.g. {{260, 23}, {1020, 777}}
```

This returns the position and size, each as pairs of integers.  The pair of `position` values denotes the window's top-left coordinate, and you can see it matches the first pair of values from `bounds`. The pair of `size` values denotes the window's width and height, respectively.

Also notice that if you take the latter pair of `bounds` values and subtract the first pair, this matches the pair of `size` values given here.

Therefore, if `bounds` is represented by a list of four variables `{x, y, a, b}`, then `position` is given by `{x, y}` and `size` is given by `{a - x, b - y}`.

You can also set both size and position using either the `bounds` or `size`/`position` properties by way of a `set` command:

```
tell app "Microsoft Powerpoint" to set the bounds of its active window to {x, y, a, b}
```

or

```
tell app "System Events" to tell process "Microsoft Powerpoint" to tell window 1 to set its size to {w, h}
```

Comment: Are you getting the output for the above code "tell application "Microsoft Powerpoint" to return the bounds of window 1"

Comment: Apple script not showing nothing in result tab in apple script editor and showing------
 tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
 get bounds of window 1
  --> current application
end tell 
-----
in replies tab

Comment: What version of AppleScript, *Script Editor* and MacOS are you using ?  It should definitely show the result of the command.  Try assigning the values to variables like this: `tell app "Microsoft Powerpoint" to set {x1,y1,x2,y2} to bounds of window 1`.

Comment: Using Apple script 2.7, Script editor2.10(194), OSX - High Sierra

Comment: Also, out of interest, what is the response when using *System Events* ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162969/discussion-between-sivaprasad-km-and-cjk).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on the latest version of Sierra

```
property currentBounds : {}
property theApp : "Microsoft Powerpoint" -- Whatever App You Want
property thePosition : {0, 22} -- Replace With Desired Numbers
property theSize : {190, 158} -- Replace With Desired Numbers
property setNewBounds : thePosition & theSize

getBounds()

-- setBounds() -- Un-Comment This For Setting Bounds


on getBounds()
    activate application theApp
    delay 1
    tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
        set currentBounds to bounds of window 1
    end tell
end getBounds

on setBounds()
    try
        activate application theApp
        delay 1
        tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
            set bounds of window 1 to setNewBounds
        end tell
    on error
        activate application theApp
        delay 1
            tell application "System Events" to tell window 1 of (process 1 where it is frontmost)
                try
                    set position to thePosition
                    set size to theSize
                end try
            end tell
    end try
end setBounds
```